# Questions regarding the overall phase and relative phases of the quantum state vector

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$
$\newcommand{\braket}[1]{\left<#1\right>}$
$\newcommand{\normsquared}[1]{\left| #1 \right|^2}$
$\newcommand{\probabilityup}[2]{\normsquared{{}_{#1}\braket{+|\psi_{#2}}}{}}$
$\newcommand{\probabilitydown}[2]{\normsquared{{}_{#1}\braket{-|\psi_{#2}}}{}}$

I'm doing problem 1.10. from McIntyre's *Quantum Mechanics* and it reads:

> **1.10** Consider the three quantum states:
>
> \begin{align}
> \ket{\psi_1} =& \dfrac{4}{5}\ket{+} + i\dfrac{3}{5}\ket{-} \\
> \ket{\psi_2} =& \dfrac{4}{5}\ket{+} - i\dfrac{3}{5}\ket{-} \\
> \ket{\psi_3} =& -\dfrac{4}{5}\ket{+} + i\dfrac{3}{5}\ket{-}
> \end{align}
>
> **a)** For each of the $\ket{\psi_i}$ above, calculate the probabilities of the spin component measurements along the $x$-, $y$-, and $z$-axes.
>
> **b)** Use your results from (a) to comment on the importance of the overall phase and of the relative phases of the quantum state vector.

My answers for (a) are:

$\probabilityup{x}{1} = \normsquared{\dfrac{4 + 3i}{5\sqrt{2}}} = \dfrac{1}{2}$ ; $\probabilitydown{x}{1} = \dfrac{1}{2}$

$\probabilityup{x}{2} = \normsquared{\dfrac{4 - 3i}{5\sqrt{2}}} = \dfrac{1}{2}$ ; $\probabilitydown{x}{2} = \dfrac{1}{2}$

$\probabilityup{x}{3} = \normsquared{\dfrac{3i - 4}{5\sqrt{2}}} = \dfrac{1}{2}$ ; $\probabilitydown{x}{3} = \dfrac{1}{2}$

$\probabilityup{y}{1} = \normsquared{\dfrac{4 - 3}{5\sqrt{2}}} = \dfrac{1}{50}$ ; $\probabilitydown{y}{1} = \dfrac{49}{50}$

$\probabilityup{y}{2} = \normsquared{\dfrac{4 + 3}{5\sqrt{2}}} = \dfrac{49}{50}$ ; $\probabilitydown{y}{2} = \dfrac{1}{50}$

$\probabilityup{y}{3} = \normsquared{\dfrac{-4 - 3}{5\sqrt{2}}} = \dfrac{49}{50}$ ; $\probabilitydown{y}{3} = \dfrac{1}{50}$

$\normsquared{\braket{+|\psi_1}} = \dfrac{16}{25}$ ; $\normsquared{\braket{-|\psi_1}} = \dfrac{9}{25}$

$\normsquared{\braket{+|\psi_2}} = \dfrac{16}{25}$ ; $\normsquared{\braket{-|\psi_2}} = \dfrac{9}{25}$

$\normsquared{\braket{+|\psi_3}} = \dfrac{16}{25}$ ; $\normsquared{\braket{-|\psi_3}} = \dfrac{9}{25}$

1) I'm quite sure that a phase is an angle that a complex number, taken to be a vector, makes with the real axis in the complex plane. Unless I'm mistaken then, each of the three $\ket{\psi_i}$ has two phases, one for each dimension of the Hilbert space. Or is it that we take the n-tuple of angles of a state to be a single phase?

2) I'm inclined to point out for part (b) that overall phases don't matter, but $\probabilityup{y}{1} \neq \probabilityup{y}{2} = \probabilityup{y}{3}$ which doesn't make sense to me if overall phases don't matter. I also don't know what my calculations tell me about relative phases. I'd appreciate it if you'd help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've correctly stated, a phase is a "pure-angle" complex number, i.e. a factor of the form $e^{i\varphi}$ (for real $\varphi$) in front of a quantum state.

As your text notes, these come in two kinds:

- **global** phases are phases that apply to all the terms in the space, or in a given superposition, so e.g. the factor $e^{i\varphi}$ in $$ |a⟩ = e^{i\varphi}\left( |0⟩+|1⟩\right). $$
- **relative** phases are those that apply to only part of the states in a given superposition, i.e. like the factor $e^{i\varphi}$ in $$ |b⟩ = |0⟩+e^{i\varphi}|1⟩. $$

Some of the states in the set you've been given **differ by a global phase**. (We say this of states $|c⟩$ and $|d⟩$ if there exists a real angle $\varphi$ such that $|c⟩=e^{i\varphi}|d⟩$.) Other pairs of states in your set of states do not have this property, and they have different relative phases in the superpositions they've been expressed as.* Your question is requiring you to identify which pairs have which relationships, to match these observations against the physical observables you've already calculated, and to draw conclusions from that comparison.

---

<sup>(* For clarity, this list is not exhaustive; as a simple third possibility, they could be superpositions with different weights or just different basis states entirely. Also, the observation "they differ by a phase" for superposition states need not be basis-independent.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. It turns out that I misunderstood what was meant by an overall phase and a relative phase. You made this clear and now I know how to approach the problem.